# Web scraping a table and can't find source code

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I am scraping this website: http://www.basket.ee/et/meistriliiga/1/ajakava-ja-tulemused/?gid=2017001101 and I am not able to get the data from the second table. First teams' statistics are in the source code but second teams' stats are not.

If I right click and watch the source code in browser then I can see both teams' table but when I scrape the data with BeautifulSoup the table is there, but no data inside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made demo for you, you can refrence this:

```
import requests, bs4

r = requests.get('http://www.basket.ee/et/meistriliiga/1/ajakava-ja-tulemused/?gid=2017001101')

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

tables = soup.find_all('table', class_='basket_table')[1:]
for table in tables:
    for tr in table('tr', attrs=False):
        row = [cell.text for cell in tr(['td', 'th'])]
        print(row)
```

out:

```
['Nr.', 'Mängija', 'Pos.', 'Min', '2p', '3p', '1p', 'KL', 'RL', 'L', 'RS', 'VL', 'BL', 'PK', 'V', 'VM', 'PNK', 'PIR']
['4', 'Paiste, Mario *', '2', '31:53', '4/7', '2/6', '1/3', '2', '1', '3', '2', '1', '0', '3', '4', '4', '15', '9']
['5', 'Post, Siim-Markus *', '1', '23:32', '1/2', '1/5', '2/5', '2', '0', '2', '2', '1', '0', '3', '5', '5', '7', '1']
['6', 'Metsalu, Oliver *', '3', '30:46', '2/7', '0/1', '0/0', '3', '2', '5', '3', '1', '0', '3', '5', '0', '4', '-1']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I managed to find a way to get my script working as well. I just replaced `"html_parser"` with `"lxml"`.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit tough to help you debug your code without any code ;-)

But, I am guessing that you either are using the [find](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) method, which only returns the first match, or you have an error in your selectors.

A quick look at the site indicates that if you use [find_all](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) and select on the 'basket_table' class you will get a list of three tables, the latter two being the ones you are looking at.

Take a look [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) for instructions how to search by css class.

Hope it helps